# Using the right article in a sentence

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

What is the right article in this sentence?

I'm talking about a regular pending icon used to indicate that an element is editable:

> When I hover a block that's being edited, it wouldn't show (a|the|)
>   pencil icon.

Comment: This isn't what you asked about (which is why I'm putting it in a comment), but you should say *hover over*, not just *hover*, and use either consistent present tense (*hover* and *won't*) or consistent past tense (*hovered* and *wouldn't*).

Comment: ... or simply (*hover* and *doesn't*) or (*hovered* and *didn't*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say *the pencil icon*, as I assume you expect one particular pencil icon, not just one of several possibilities. But either one is fine, honestly.